# Change global variable in php controller

Tags: php, laravel, variables, controller, controls

I tried changing the value of my global variable $winLogBook but it won't seem to work globally only locally.

```
public $winLogBook = "nothing";

public function setLog(){
      $this->winLogBook = "somethin";
    }
```

My output: "nothing"

```
$controller->setLog();    
echo $this->winLogBook;
```

My full code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\fieldModel;

class losOpController extends Controller
{
public $winLogBook = "nothing";
public function setLog(){
      $this->winLogBook = "somethin";
        }
public function printLogBook(){
        echo $this->winLogBook;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @MartijinTotte can you call `setLog` method ?

Comment: call setLog and return it in this function as well.

Comment: Use the `global` keyword to import from the application scope.

Comment: @JigneshJoisar i did just forgot to implement it in the question $controller->setLog();

Comment: @SaifurRehman its a set function just like in java I wouldn't have to return anything right?

Comment: @hardiksolanki sorry where should I use the global keyword?

Comment: Please write all code with object creation because it is unable to find where did you add echo inside the class or outside.

Comment: If you are using inside class then right. If not check `echo $controller->winLogBook;`

Comment: @MartijnTotté You need to use global keyword into `setLog` function. Like `global $winLogBook;`

Comment: @MartijnTotté you are right . he has to call that function before accessing that variable.

Comment: @RohitRasela I edited now

Comment: @RohitRasela you are a god. Why do I have to use $this in the function and $controller in the echo?

Comment: @hardiksolanki thank you for your help but the global $winLogBook returns a syntax error

Comment: You can not write this syntax `echo $this->winLogBook;` inside the class directly

Comment: Where are you creating object of the `losOpController` class?

Comment: @RohitRasela in my web.php im calling a function in that class called printLogbook

Comment: @MartijnTotté check it by `$controller->printLogBook();` or by `echo  $controller-> winLogBook`

Comment: @MartijnTotté please rewrite your question because we don't have global in class but we can change value as values passed by reference in PHP OOP. So It would like to log your routes then you can create middleware for that in Laravel.